# MChip Select 4 tag values (9F7E and D5)

Tags: emv

I'm working on a profile for MasterCard EMV cards on M/Chip Select 4 version 1.1b and I need some help understanding the data elements for the 9F7E (Application Life Cycle Data) tag value and D5 (Application Control) tag value. Unfortunately, the MasterCard SSF form doesn't explain information. From our card vendor we found a document in which we found application Id number is it similar to ALCD(9F7E)? And how could could I found D5 value

Answer (score 1):

9F7E is a 48 bytes long field organized into two 4 parts.

2 bytes - version number - for your case 03

7 bytes - type approval id - which is provided by MasterCard while 
certifying applet.

20 bytes - Contents are issuer specific denoting application identification.

20 bytes application code identification

---

For options available on D5, download MChip 4 Version 1.1 Issuer Guide to Debit and Credit Parameter Management.pdf from MasterCard Connect. It has bit by bit information.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this informations in:
M/Chip 4 Version 1.1 Issuer Guide to Debit and Credit Parameter Management

There, you will see next (tag D5 value related):
The Application Control activates or de-activates functions in the application.
The coding of the Application Control data element varies depending on the
version of M/Chip 4, and on whether the Lite or Select application is being
used.

You are using M/Chip Select 4 version 1.1b, so, there it is:
[image: M/Chip Select 4 version 1.1b, Byte 1]

And, if you have M/Chip Lite 4 version 1.1b, first byte will be like:
[image: M/Chip Lite 4 version 1.1b, Byte]

Second byte value is same for both:
[image: M/Chip (Lite and Select) 4 application version 1.1b, Byte 2]

Hope this can help you.